# Whats the proper keytool command to get facebook app signature on android?

Tags: android, facebook, keytool

I am trying to use openssl to export the key for my app. I followed the facebook developers guide but I am stuck when it comes to the keytool command.

Facebook has it this way:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

I have mine this way:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\keytool" -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\blah\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\blah\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\blah\bin\openssl" base64
```

I run openssl.exe as an administrator. When I run the above command, it says `"Openssl Error: "C:\program files\java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\keytool`"" is an invalid command.

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I got it to work on Windows 7 by doing the following:

1. Copy the entire bin directory from the openssl install to the jdk.x.x\bin directory where the keytool is.
2. Run the command as shown in the facebook doc as follows:

   ```
   keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\MYUSER\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
   ```
3. It asks for a password (only once) which is android

Hope this works for you